# Ubuntu terminal ssh to same ip after device changed

Tags: bash, ssh, alias

I ssh to a device that gets attached to a test bench with the following:`ssh root@1.2.3.4`

Because the actual device has been changed since the last time I connected to that IP I get:`WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!` all as expected. The warning tells me that I can easily fix this with `ssh-keygen -f "/home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "1.2.3.4"`

I do find it repeating the same thing over and over, there must be some way to improve this. I know this IP and it is internal to my company.

I started working on trying to use something like `!!:s/find/replace` but the spaces in the replace is making my life difficult.

What is the easiest way to automate this, maybe create an alias?

Thank you
Jack

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh << that might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a senior dev at my company and he suggested that I just update my ~/.ssh.config file. I added:

```
Host 1.2.3.*
 User root
 UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
 StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

No more having to copy and paste the line to update my known_host file